# SQL Server, sort on two columns，first asc sort,second asc or desc based on the first odd-even

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort a table based on two columns, first asc sort, and second if the first fields is odd then asc sort, if the first fields is even then desc sort.

For example I have some data in a table

[image]

I want sort it to like that

[image]

How to write this sql?

Comment: sql-server,but if you can write in both database ,it cound't be better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply `ORDER BY -1 * SecondField` when `FirstField` is even.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1742/0)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY
    FirstField,
    CASE 
        WHEN FirstField % 2 = 0 THEN -1 * SecondField
        ELSE SecondField
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use three orderings, and keep the unused one constant:

```
select *
from myTable
order by FirstField,
    case when FirstField % 2 = 0 then SecondField else 0 end desc,
    case when FirstField % 2 = 1 then SecondField else 0 end asc
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c437/1)